# pull value from object -> array -> object -> object mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have this following strtucture

```
{
  _id: ".....",
  a: {
    a1:".......",
    b: [
      b1: {
        b11: "......",
        b12: "......",
      },
      b2: {
        b21: "......",
        b22: "......",
        d: {},
      },
      c:{
        c1: {
          ......
        },
        d: {

        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here I want to check if property `d` exists or not inside `b`, it may exists in multiple objects inside `b`, if exists pull the `d` object from record.

**Note**: There might be a chance that property `d` exists multiple times inside `b1` and `b2`, In this case I want to remove it from all objects

I tried like

```
Coll.find({ 'a.b': { $elemMatch: { 'c': { d: { $exists: true } } } } })
```

but it is not returning anything although there are record, any help appreciated.

I want to pull that data from record too.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
Coll.find({ 'a.b.c.d'{ $exists: true } })
```

that worked for me but still no idea how to use positional operator to pull the value from record

Answer (score 1):

***Please take a little more time forming your questions*** to make them easier to answer: your example data has key-values inside a list (invalid), your question mentions $elemMatch which is a list operator, you talk about removing things but never follow up that thought, and then your UPDATE switches gears and implies it is an object hierarchy.

Taking a hint from your UPDATE, I created some valid data - paste this into mongo shell (perhaps in the test database):

```
db.test.insert({
  a: {
    a1: "a1",
    b: {
      b1: {
        b11: "b11",
        b12: "b12",
      },
      b2: {
        b21: "b21",
        b22: "b22",
        d: {},
      },
      c: {
        c1: {
          c1: "......"
        },
        d: {
          d1: "woo hoo, struck gold"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Inside the mongo shell, everything is javascript so "positional operators" are the dot and array subscript operator. A mongo find() returns an array of documents. If you want the the d document (object) from the first doc returned from the query

```
db.test.find({'a.b.c.d': {$exists: true}})[0].a.b.c.d
```

produces

```
{
  "d1": "woo hoo, struck gold"
}
```

**UPDATE**: Adding detail in response to comment.

If you want to remove the a.b.c.d sub-document, use `$unset`

```
// remove sub-document a.b.c.d
db.test.update({}, {$unset: {'a.b.c.d': ''}});
// look at the document to verify that a.b.c.d is removed
db.test.find();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, here `b` is array of objects, my record structure is correct I feel, . Coming to your answer I want to remove `object d` from record not to get the data, I can read the data, but to pull data from record I can't find exact query

Comment: On arrays: try to insert your example into a collection - review the error. On removing: use $unset to remove a single field. Updating my answer to show how.